# findbugs is objecting to anonymous inner class

Tags: java, findbugs, sonarqube

This code:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>> theSet =  new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e1, final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e2) {
            return e2.getValue().getStartTime().compareTo(e1.getValue().getStartTime());
        }
    }));
```

triggers a violation in Sonar, tripping the findbugs rule "SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON" which has the description:

> This class is an inner class, but does not use its embedded reference
>   to the object which created it.  This reference makes the instances of
>   the class larger, and may keep the reference to the creator object
>   alive longer than necessary.  If possible, the class should be made
>   into a static inner class. Since anonymous inner classes cannot be
>   marked as static, doing this will require refactoring the inner class
>   so that it is a named inner class.

Really? Isn't this very nit-picky? Should I really refactor a one line method in an anonymous inner class to save the cost of an extra reference ? In this case, there's no possibility of it holding the reference longer than necessary.

I don't mind doing it as our strongly enforced coding standards are "zero sonar violations" but I'm strongly tempted to argue the case for a `//NOSONAR` here, as imho extracting a one line method to a static inner makes the code slightly harder to grok.

What do the java purists think?

Comment: Since that class is stateless you could go one better and declare the comparator as a `static final`, using the same instance for all calls rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of static code analysis tools to be nit-picky? There is a clear technical reason for complaining about this. Just disable the rule if you don't want it for some project.

Comment: ...to continue, even if application of some rule seems unnecessary in some situation, I'd take the stance that disabling the rule for that one case needs a *strong* reason, and this isn't strong enough reason. Either disable the entire rule, or follow it.

Comment: well, I'm generally ok with most of findbugs rules but this one stood out as an extremely nit-picky one. This particular (small internal swing based testing tool) app could end up using a lot of anonymous inner classes. I'm not in control of what sonar rules are enabled/disabled, its a development center standard but as this is an internal tool I can probaly create a dedicated  and slightly more relaxed profile for it. I do like to be fully compliant though, even on internal projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Converting comments to answer, first of all I could be persuaded that having this as anonymous inner class can be justified, even if there's a clear technical reason for being nit-picky about this.

Still, I would say: **Follow the rules you have set**. Rules create consistency, and when all the code is written the same way, the code base is easier to understand as a whole. If some rule is bad, disable it everywhere.

When there is an exception, there's also need to explain why there's exception: an extra mental burden for someone reading the code, an extra item to discuss in code review, etc. Only disable rules in individual cases if you can argue it is somehow an *exceptional* case.

Also, I'm not sure doing it as static class would be less understandable, even if it adds a bit more boilerplate (and sorry if below is not 100% correct code, my Java is a bit rusty, feel free to suggest edit):

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>> theSet 
    = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>(new SSGSessionStartTimeComparator());
```

And then somewhere else in the file, together with other static classes:

```
static class SSGSessionStartTimeComparator extends Comparator<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e1, final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e2) {
        return e2.getValue().getStartTime().compareTo(e1.getValue().getStartTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add `implements Serializable` to the declaration of `SSGSessionStartTimeComparator` in order to also follow the SE_COMPARATOR_SHOULD_BE_SERIALIZABLE rule (not in scope for this question, but imho, generally a good idea).

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness' sake, I'd like to add another variant to the excellent answers already provided. Define a constant for the `Comparator`, and use that:

```
private static final Comparator<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>> BY_STARTTIME =
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e1,
            final Map.Entry<String, SSGSession> e2) {
        return e2.getValue().getStartTime().compareTo(e1.getValue().getStartTime());
    }
};

private void foo() {
    Set<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>> theSet =
        new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, SSGSession>>(BY_STARTTIME);
}
```

This saves you the additional class as in [hyde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996986/1005481). Otherwise, hyde's answer is better, because it allows you to declare the `Comparator` to be serializable (which it is, because it has no state). If the `Comparator` is not serializable, your `TreeSet` won't be serializable either.

Answer (score 2):

There are three solutions here, the best of which is out of your control:

- Extend the Java syntax:

  ```
  ... theSet = new static Comparator ...
  ```
- Declare and use a static class as described.
- Ignore the warning in this one instance:

  ```
  @SuppressFBWarnings("SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON")
  ... your method ...
  ```

I prefer the first, but that's a long time coming if ever. Thus I would go for the last before ignoring the rule project-wide. Choosing a rule should entail a little pain to override it; otherwise it's merely a convention or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: anonymous inner classes are great way to leak memory, especially when used in JEE beans. Something as simple:
`new HashMap<>() {{
    put"("a","b");
}};`

in bean annotated with @javax.ejb.Singleton might lead to multiple instanced being kept alive as that Map keeps reference to bean.